# DWA planner failed to produce path

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a navigation framework using move_base with DWAPlannerROS as the local planner/controller on ROS Melodic.

Whenever I set a goal, the global planning is successful but the DWAPlannerROS doesn't work well. In fact, it only appears to get a trajectory very sporadically. Most of the times, it throws a

**"DWA planner failed to produce path"**-Warning

and quits at some point.

Therefore, my terminal output looks as follows:
[image: terminal output]

The corresponding rviz-visualization (with activated global and local costmap) looks as follows:
[image: rviz-visualization]

**Note** that the trajectory that can be seen in this visualization is one of the mentioned sporadically occuring trajectories which has been computed a couple of seconds before the screenshot was taken!

I've read some other posts solved the issue **using the turtlebot-params**. I've tried that but the **issue remained**. Other threads suggested to use default parameters and then tune every single parameter in order so see which parameter causes the problem, but when **using only default-params** the **issue remained**, too.

At the moment I'm using the following params:

**base_global_planner_params.yaml:**

```
GlobalPlanner:
  #basic parameters
  default_tolerance: 3.0  #default is 0.0
  use_dijkstra: true  #default is true
  old_navfn_behavior: false  #default is false
  use_quadratic: true  #default is true
  use_grid_path: false  #default is false
  allow_unknown: true  #default is true
  lethal_cost: 253  #default is 253
  neutral_cost: 50  #default is 50
  cost_factor: 3  #default is 3

  #debug parameters
  publish_potential: True
```

**base_local_planner_params.yaml:**

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 3.7
  max_vel_y: 0.0
  min_vel_y: 0.0
  max_vel_trans: 3.7 
  min_vel_trans: 0.0
  max_vel_theta: 2.09 
  min_vel_theta: 0

  acc_lim_x: 2.47 
  acc_lim_y: 0
  acc_lim_theta: 4.18 
  
  sim_time: 2.0
  vx_samples: 3
  vy_samples: 0
  vth_samples: 20

  holonomic_robot: false
```

**move_base_params.yaml:**

```
controller_frequency: 5.0
controller_patience: 3.0


planner_frequency: 1.0
planner_patience: 5.0

oscillation_timeout: 10.0
oscillation_distance: 0.2

base_global_planner: "global_planner/GlobalPlanner"

base_local_planner: "dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS"
recovery_behavior_enabled: false
```

**costmap_common_params.yaml:**

```
footprint: [[0.20, 0.24125], [0.20, 0.175], [0.65, 0.175], [0.65, -0.175], [0.20, -0.175], [0.20, -0.24125], [-0.20, -0.24125], [-0.20, -0.175], [-0.65, -0.175], [-0.65, 0.175], [-0.20, 0.175], [-0.20, 0.24125]]
inflation_radius: 0.1
transform_tolerance: 0.05
```

**global_costmap_params.yaml:**

```
global_costmap:
  plugins: 
    - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
  track_unknown_space: true
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 10.0 # data comes in
  publish_frequency: 10.0 # costmap publishes info
  rolling_window: true
  recovery_behavior: false
  width: 100
  height: 100
  static_layer:
      trinary_costmap: false
      map_topic: "path_segmentation_occgrid"
```

**Note** that the occupancy grid which is used as map_topic gets updated/published every 5 seconds.

**local_costmap_params:**

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom 
  map_topic: "semi_global_map"
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 10.0 
  publish_frequency: 10.0 
  track_unknown_space: true
  static_map: true
  rolling_window: true
  width: 10
  height: 10
plugins: 
- {name: static_layer2, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer2, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

Does anyone have an idea on what could be the issue?

Thank you in advance for any hint!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364176/dwa-planner-failed-to-produce-path./) by [Zimba96](https://answers.ros.org/users/34594/zimba96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2020-10-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out:
The issue appears to be with the

```
track_unknown_space: true
```

inside the local_costmap_params. Apparently, the DWAPlanner cannot handle unknown-areas (represented by NO_INFORMATION-cost values) properly. By setting **track_unknown_space** to **false**, the unknown-area is treated like free-space and the local planner works perfectly fine.

---

Originally posted by [Zimba96](https://answers.ros.org/users/34594/zimba96/) with karma: 121 on 2020-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2